# Error building Player: Curl error 52: Empty reply from server during unity build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a unity game and i'm getting this error:`Error building Player: Curl error 52: Empty reply from server`

Where could be the problem?

Comment: Oddly I had that the other day, I needed to click build so it bought the popup and then build from there it seemed to not have a local destination and wasnt also setup for remote build so that seemed to be its result

Answer (score 0):

This error (52, 56, etc) is a known [unity editor bug](https://forum.unity.com/threads/whats-curl-error-56.794703/), you can ignore it.